# Getting current user in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm having a lot of trouble over getting the current user that is uploading image in django rest framework.

Django rest framework is an app inside the pure django that is used for webpage.

Im using django rest framework so that users can upload files on our server... Everything works great except we need to know who was the user that uploaded it. I really tried many solutions that this site and google has to offer but just can't make it work. Here is the code from the app. What do we have to do?

**viewset.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from api.serializers import UploadedImageSerializer # import our serializer
from api.models import UploadedImage # import our model

class UploadedImagesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UploadedImage.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
    serializer_class = UploadedImageSerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UploadedImage # Import our UploadedImage model


class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Create a custom method field
# current_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_user')

class Meta:
    model = UploadedImage
    fields = ('id', 'image','name','Tip','curent_user') # only serialize the primary key and the image field
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid,os
import sqlite3
import Function1
import Function2
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def scramble_uploaded_filename(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]

    return "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), extension)

def filename(instance, filename):
    return filename


# Our main model: Uploaded Image
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField("Uploaded image",upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename)
    Tip = models.IntegerField("Captcha type")
    curent_user = models.CharField("Curent user",editable=False,max_length=100,default='')

    def filen(self) :
        path = self.image.path
        tip = self.Tip
        writez = Function1.File_input(path,tip)
        text = Function2.File_input (writez,0.83,tip)
        return text
    name = filen
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from api.serializers import UploadedImageSerializer
from api.models import UploadedImage


class UploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint
    """
    queryset = UploadedImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadedImageSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. You make a a ForeignKey inside the upload Class (in my case Post) and link it to the User(don't forget to make migrations and migrate). In your View when you render the form  go with `instance = form.save(commit = False)` -> `instance.uploaded_by = request.user`-> `instance.save()` so you fetch the current user and its saved in the Post(upload) Model.

views.py:

```
def upload(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.uploaded_by = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
       uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',default=1,related_name='uploads')
       ...
```

To see the User in the Admin you would have to install the field "uploaded_by" in your apps admin.py. I assume you know how to if not google will help you ;) 
Hope that helped.

Comment: I have some progress with your code it helped me to understand basic principle of how it works. I will get back to you after i figure out. Ty for your help.

Comment: So it shows in the Admin? What was that other comment you wrote? Had trouble with the id? sounds like you need to define def `__str__(self):
  return self.user.userprofile.name` in the Model. Did my Code bring you the Solution or you found your own way of doing it? Anyway im glad that you made it.

Comment: I installed(registered) "PostForm" in admin.py and I can see it just fine. Yes, I had trouble with user Id... This are id's and users that I had id db {{id:1,name:John},{id:2,name:Robby},{id:3,name:Mary}}.. and with your code it always showed John and it didn't matter who was logged in. After combination of yours and @AremSudoma  code I figure it out. Now it works great. Only thing left to do is catch Header of user so I could see IP from where they made post :) Ty!!

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work. I gave the guy an up vote so his work is recognized ;) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

In my projects I use HiddenField for filling the current user. For example for your case:

```
class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = UploadedImage
        fields = ('id', 'image','name','Tip','current_user')
```

Comment: Combination of your code and @hansTheFranz  was the wining solution for me. tnx